# How to protect routes in React 18?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an admin dashboard and want that only admins are able to see the pages. So I set a condition into my router. When I am logged in, I am able to open every page, but I get the warning:

> No routes matched location “/pagename”

Navbar and Sidebar staying in the same position, so that every page opens in a div named ContentWrapper.
How can I get rid of this warning?

Code:

```
 const admin = useAppSelector((state)=>state.auth.user?.isAdmin);
  return (
   
    <Container>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<Login/>}/>
      </Routes>
      {admin && 
    <>
      <Navbar/>
      <Wrapper>
        <Sidebar/>
        <ContentWrapper>
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
              <Route path="/sales" element={<Sales/>}/>
              <Route path="/analytics" element={<Analytics/>}/>
              <Route path="/transactions" element={<Transactions/>}/>
              <Route path="/reports" element={<Reports/>}/>
              <Route path="/mail" element={<Mail/>}/>
              <Route path="/feedback" element={<Feedback/>}/>
              <Route path="/messages" element={<Messages/>}/>
              <Route path="/manage" element={<Manage/>}/>
              <Route path="/user" element={<User/>}/>
              <Route path="/products" element={<Products/>}/>
              <Route path="/productlistChild" element={<ProductlistChild/>}/>
              <Route path="/productlistWomen" element={<ProductlistWomen/>}/>
              <Route path="/productlistMen" element={<ProductlisttMen/>}/>
              <Route path="/productlistSportschuhe" element={<ProductlistSportschuhe/>}/>
              <Route path="/productlistSneaker" element={<ProductlistSneaker/>}/>
              <Route path="/cardImages" element={<CardImages/>}/>
              <Route path="/sneakerImage" element={<SneakerImage/>}/>
              <Route path="/sliderImage" element={<SliderImages/>}/>
              <Route path="/newsletterBackground" element={<NewsletterBackground/>}/>
              <Route path="/descriptionItems" element={<DescriptionItems/>}/>
              </Routes>
          </ContentWrapper>
        </Wrapper>
        </>
        }
      </Router>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: add `<Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />` in the Routes list for not found some custom route incase not matching pattern or name of route. Also in not found element you can add custom 404 page to display page not found.

Comment: @NIKUNJKOTHIYA Thanks for your response. I have done that, but the warning stays.

Comment: Why do you redirect to a path that you are not listing it as a Route?

Comment: @juxhinbleta Thanks, but I not exactly understood what you mean. I have this login and only the logged in admin should see anything on screen including navbar and sidebar.

Comment: I was asking about `pagename` route. Anyway, I would suggest you organize your routes as Authorized/UnAuthorized and then manage your user roles. Don't forget to add `path="*" `, you need that as a fallback. Start with a basic router and then extend it. Do not include conditional `jsx` in `Routes`, rather create a component that returns your combined `Routes` as a single component.

Comment: @juxhinbleta Okay, pagename was only a placeholder for saying that every page has this warning. I added a path="*". I try to use a component.

Answer (score 0):

Did something similar recently

You can create a `PrivateRoute Component`

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRouteAdmin = ({ isLoggedIn, role }) => {
  return isLoggedIn && role === 'Admin' ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
};

export default PrivateRouteAdmin;
```

and then you can use it in your App.js like this

```
      <Route element={<PrivateRouteAdmin isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} role={user?.data?.role} />}>
        <Route element={<DashboardWrapper />}>
          {PublicRoutesAdmin.map((route, index) => {
            return <Route key={index} path={route.path} element={<route.component />} />;
          })}
        </Route>
      </Route>
```

`PublicRoutesAdmin.map` has just all the routes in a separate file, nothing fancy.

You can have other public routes pout of the private route component

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve this by creating two groups of routes: Private and Public:

```
const PublicRoutes = () => (
    <Fragment>
        <Route path="/public/a"><ComponentA /></Route>
        <Route path="/public/b"><ComponentB /></Route>
    </Fragment>
)

const PrivateRoutes = () => (
    <Fragment>
        <Route path="/private/a"><PrivComponentA /></Route>
        <Route path="/private/b"><PrivComponentB /></Route>
    </Fragment>
)
```

And then have a RootRouter component which conditionally renders either the public or the private routes based on a condition:

```
const RootRouter = () => {

    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                {admin ? 
                    <Fragment> 
                        <PublicRoutes />
                        <PrivateRoutes />
                    </Fragment> : 
                    <PublicRoutes />
                }
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

This way, you are rendering the `PublicRoutes` AND the `PrivateRoutes` for the `admin`, but only the `PublicRoutes` for non-admin users.